# Book where a soldier is transported to an alternative Earth during the Battle of Verdun (WW1)

Tags: story-identification, books, parallel-universe

This is a long-shot as I remember very little about the book. It may not even have been written in English, but in Dutch.

I read this in the first half of the 1980's. Got it from my school library. I read it in Dutch (had to be Dutch because the school library only had "proper literature" in English), but chances are it was a translation of an English original as there is not that much original SF/Fantasy in Dutch.

A soldier (USA I think) is fighting at Verdun during the infamous World War 1 battle. He enters a cave or tunnel beneath the city (possibly hidden and revealed by a bomb explosion during the battle).
The cave/tunnel transports him to an alternative reality, fantasy/medieval style where the city also exists, but it is now called "Dun" or "Dunn".

I seem to recall that in the alternative universe the city is under siege as well. The protagonist has some adventures (I can't recall any of them) and I also can't remember if he eventually makes it back to the normal Verdun.
(It may even be the case he goes back and forth several times now I think about it.)

There is very little to go on, but somehow this book lingered in the back of my mind, so it must have made some impression on me. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: @ZeissIkon My edit mainly changed formatting and some grammar; not any detail changes. If there is anything let me know and I will change it back though...

Comment: Yeah, I looked at your edit, and it seems I just scanned the question a little *too* rapidly before starting to type.  Publication date alone would rule out my answer, never mind being in Dutch (can't say Pratchett has never been translated, but Dutch isn't one of the big language to translate to).

Comment: @ZeissIkon Pratchett seems very unlikely for this book. And for the record: Most of his work is translated in Dutch. Dutch has about 25 million potential readers worldwide (Netherlands, Belgium, parts of the Caribbean, Suriname and lot's of immigrants to USA, Canada, Australia) and there is a surprisingly large and thriving market for translated works. It is not just the best-sellers that get translated to Dutch.

Comment: FWIW Zeiss' answer was about _The Long Earth_ so may be worth checking out.

Comment: I wouldn't have deleted the answer for date and language alone -- nothing else in *The Long Earth* matches the details of the question.

Comment: [Hoe Ver Is Dunn? by Jaap Verduyn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18073379-hoe-ver-is-dunn)?

Comment: @JohnRennie My God... That's it. I recognize the cover. So it was a Dutch novel after all. Make it an answer and you'll get the bounty!

Comment: Boom! :-) I looked for the book when you first posted the question but couldn't find it. When I saw you'd posted a bounty I thought I'd have one last try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hoe Ver Is Dunn?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18073379-hoe-ver-is-dunn) by Jaap Verduyn.

[image]

I cannot find a copy of the book to confirm the identification but it roughly matches.

Comment: Just did a search in my huge collection of ebooks that I grabbed from usenet and torrents over the last 20 years and I found a copy buried in there. It really is the book I was looking for. Unfortunately the ebook is almost unreadable. Missing sentences/paragraphs and lots of OCR errors. So I will have to track down a good copy, which is going to be a challenge.

Comment: Apparently this is an extended version of an earlier book called "Pentagram in de Toren". I can find Pentagram for sale, but this one is hard to get.

Comment: Looks like the publisher reused one of the Frazetta covers from the Lancer Conan series of the late '60s

Comment: @user888379 I think you're right. If it isn't one of those it is a good imitation. I've got a 2nd hand copy of this book on order now. When I get it delivered I will check the cover-art attribution.

Comment: @user888379 I finally acquired my own copy (1st order fell through and I had to find another 2nd hand copy) and I can now confirm the cover is by Frank Frazetta.